# Rolling function in pandas with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04"] * 2,
        "group": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
        "x": [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 2],
        "condition": [1, 0, 1, 0] * 2
    }
)
df
```

I want to calculate, the rolling average of the column x:

- Per group
- Using only past data (not using the current row)
- Using only data for the rolling average where `condition = 1`.

The outcome should be the following:

[image]

How can I do that in pandas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we should filter the dataframe on conditions and then calculate the mean of x

- group == group of current row
- date < date of current row
- condition == 1

`df.apply` is used to apply to all rows of the dataframe

```
df['rolling_avg_x'] = df.apply(lambda x: df[(df.group == x.group) & (df.date < x.date) & (df.condition == 1)].x.mean(), axis=1)
```

This will give you the output as desire